# add item to a listbox using jquery

Tags: jquery

How to add item to a listBox using jquery.

for example in the following listbox

```
<option value="1"></option>
<option value="2">item 2</option>
<option value="3">item 3</option>
<option value="4">item 4</option>
<option value="0">All</option>
```

Comment: There are no listboxes in HTML. Do you mean a `<select>`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
$('#Select1').append('<option value="5">item 5</option>'); // adds item 5 at the end
$('#Select1 option').eq(0).after('<option value="new">new</option>'); // add new at the second position.
```

Answer (score 11):

Several methods are there. You can use

```
$('<option value="5">item 5</option>').appendTo('#listbox');

$('#listbox').append('<option value="5">item 5</option>');
```